# How do I bulkinsert arraylist of objects - Android Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert

How do I perform bulkInsert on arraylist of objects?

I have an arraylist of Book and I want to  use the bulkInsert function of Content Provider to insert in bulk a list of Books;

here is arraylist of book:

```
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList;

here is my code where I try to do bulkinsert
// insert data into database
public void insertData() {

   ContentValues bookValues = new ContentValues();


   for(Book book: bookList){
       bookValues = new ContentValues();
       bookValues.put(BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMN_ID, Book.getBook_id());
       bookValues.put(BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, Book.getTitle());
       bookValues.put(BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMN_OVERVIEW, Book.getDescription());


   }


   // Finally, insert Book data into the database.
       getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
               BookContract.BookEntry.CONTENT_URI, bookValues
       );



   }
```

Comment: `bulkInsert()` takes an array of `ContentValues`. So, create an array, sized to match the size of whatever `bookList` is. Iterate over `bookList` as you are, but put each `ContentValues` into the array. Then, pass the array of `ContentValues` to `bulkInsert()`.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare that makes sense to me. I'm a bit rusty at Java so I'd like to know if there is an example of code of what you just described?